# Where does magento check for "special price to date" field?

Tags: magento

A product has "special  price to date" field.

Where is the logic located for that? Anybody knows? I mean php file

Please help

Answer (score 2):

For Magento 1.8.1
The main function is "isStoreDateInInterval" located in

```
app\code\local\Mage\Core\Model\Locale.php (line number:804)
```

Calculate and apply special price function "calculateSpecialPrice" located in

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price.php (line number: 407)
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto admin>Catalog>Manage Product>Select a product >goto Price here you will find special price from Price tab

Here the picture[image]

Comment: I mean logic in php file!